# Operator pending mode remaps not working

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, map-operator

I'm trying to build a vimscript can be used with the Dvorak Simplified Layout. I.e., given that the keys on the keyboard plugged into the computer are laid out in the Dovark Simplified Layout (and the system's keyboard settings are set accordingly), I want to write a vimscript that will make vim use the Dvorak layout only in Insert mode: in all other modes, the keyboard layout will be QWERTY.

Here's what I have:

```
"Keys between the 0 and the backspace
noremap [ -
noremap { _
noremap ] =
noremap } +

"Keys from the tab till the end of the row
noremap ' q
noremap " Q
noremap , w
noremap < W
noremap . e
noremap > E
noremap p r
noremap P R
noremap y t
noremap Y T
noremap f y
noremap F Y
noremap g u
noremap G U
noremap c i
noremap C I
noremap r o
noremap R O
noremap l p
noremap L P
noremap / [
noremap ? {
noremap = ]
noremap + }

"Home row keys
noremap o s
noremap O S
noremap e d
noremap E D
noremap u f
noremap U F
noremap i g
noremap I G
noremap d h
noremap D H
noremap h j
noremap H J
noremap t k
noremap T K
noremap n l
noremap N L
noremap s ;
noremap S :
noremap - ,
noremap _ "

"Keys for the row below the home row
noremap ; z
noremap : Z
noremap q x
noremap Q X
noremap j c
noremap J C
noremap k v
noremap K V
noremap x b
noremap X B
noremap b n
noremap B N
noremap w ,
noremap W <
noremap v .
noremap v >
noremap z /
noremap Z ?

"Same as above but now for the console

"Keys between the 0 and the backspace
cnoremap [ -
cnoremap { _
cnoremap ] =
cnoremap } +

"Keys from the tab till the end of the row
cnoremap ' q
cnoremap " Q
cnoremap , w
cnoremap < W
cnoremap . e
cnoremap > E
cnoremap p r
cnoremap P R
cnoremap y t
cnoremap Y T
cnoremap f y
cnoremap F Y
cnoremap g u
cnoremap G U
cnoremap c i
cnoremap C I
cnoremap r o
cnoremap R O
cnoremap l p
cnoremap L P
cnoremap / [
cnoremap ? {
cnoremap = ]
cnoremap + }

"Home row keys
cnoremap o s
cnoremap O S
cnoremap e d
cnoremap E D
cnoremap u f
cnoremap U F
cnoremap i g
cnoremap I G
cnoremap d h
cnoremap D H
cnoremap h j
cnoremap H J
cnoremap t k
cnoremap T K
cnoremap n l
cnoremap N L
cnoremap s ;
cnoremap S :
cnoremap - ,
cnoremap _ "

"Keys for the row below the home row
cnoremap ; z
cnoremap : Z
cnoremap q x
cnoremap Q X
cnoremap j c
cnoremap J C
cnoremap k v
cnoremap K V
cnoremap x b
cnoremap X B
cnoremap b n
cnoremap B N
cnoremap w ,
cnoremap W <
cnoremap v .
cnoremap v >
cnoremap z /
cnoremap Z ?
```

But for some reason, pressing "ii" on the physical keyboard, which ought to jump to the beginning of the document (since in both Normal mode and Operator-Pending modes the "i" key maps to a "g"), vim goes into Insert mode. However, pressing "ig" on the physical keyboard does jump to the beginning of the document.

The problem persists whether on Linux or on Windows.

Why are the operating-pending mode maps not working? Vim help says that "noremap" remaps all modes except Insert, Console, Terminal-Job, and Lang-Arg.

Comment: Have you tried `:help dvorak` in vim? I remember there being something useful for dvorak keyboard users in there.

Comment: Actually, check out the dvorak file in runtime/lang; https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/keymap/dvorak.vim

Answer (score 2):

Well, `gg` is a full command by itself, so operator mode is not involved here at all.

It's not like the first `g` is a command and then  the second `g` is an operator. The `g`-*something* family of commands are simply two-character commands.

In order to have `ii` to map to `gg`, you actually need:

```
noremap ii gg
```

Though you'll probably need to map all the other `i`-*something* commands to their non-dvorak counterparts.

As recommended by @DBenKnoble in the comments, check out the [dvorak.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/keymap/dvorak.vim) which is probably already installed in your vim, it probably does what you want and, if not, you can probably use it as a starting point.