# How to map number keys within motions typed during the operator-pending mode?

Tags: key-bindings

Typing source code is easier for me when the numbers row above the letters (the numrow) is permanently shifted, giving me access to the symbols at a single keypress, without pressing `Shift`. The numbers themselves are available when pressing `Shift` of course. To achieve this, I use the following in my configuration:

```
nnoremap 1 !
nnoremap 2 @
nnoremap 3 #
nnoremap 4 $
" etc...

vnoremap 1 !
vnoremap 2 @
vnoremap 3 #
vnoremap 4 $
" etc...

onoremap 1 !
onoremap 2 @
onoremap 3 #
onoremap 4 $
" etc...

" the inverse maps not included here
```

This works great normally, but I have a problem. The command for 'select everything inside parantheses', namely `vi)`, isn't working as expected, because I **still** have to press `Shift` for `)`, otherwise Vim will receive the command `vi0`, which isn't what I want.

What I want is to press `vi0` but have the `0` mapped to `)` without shifting. Unfortunately, `onoremap 0 )` didn't have any effect. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator pending mode remaps not working](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/operator-pending-mode-remaps-not-working)

Comment: Take a look at [keymap files](https://vimhelp.org/mbyte.txt.html#mbyte-keymap), the `:loadkeymap` command and the `'keymap'` option. That's a better fit for what you're trying to do. (I can turn this into an answer if it works for you.)

Comment: @filbranden As far as I know, `keymap` only works for insert mode. Does it work in normal and visual modes?

Comment: @filbranden The question you linked might indeed be the same case - `ya)` is an entire Vim command, isn't it? Then I can remap those instead...

Comment: You may just need to onoremap i) and friends

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just tried `onoremap i0 i)` and it didn't transform `vi0` into `vi)`, unfortunately.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble My mistake: `onoremap i0 i)` actually works, but for `di0`. For `vi0`, I needed `vnoremap i0 i)` and it worked. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @filbranden The question you linked does indeed look similar, although the solution in my case was to remap *text objects* in operator-pending and visual modes. I can't tell if my question is a duplicate. If you still think it is, I'll mark it as duplicate indeed.

Comment: You *probably* want xnoremap, and id say this isnt really a dupe. @CamilB if you have a solution, self-answer!

Comment: @CamilB I still think it's a duplicate (and should be marked as such), but I added an answer fully exploring your particular case and including some recommendations of possibly better approaches (such as O.S. keyboard mappings) that you might want to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim maps will handle commands, not individual keystrokes, so if you want to remap your keys, you'll need to handle two character commands which use one of those keys explicitly.

In the example you brought up, `vi)`, you'll want to create new Visual and operator-pending mappings for `i)` (and `a)` which is similar):

```
onoremap i0 i)
vnoremap i0 i)
onoremap a0 a)
vnoremap a0 a)
```

But then you'll see that there are more such two character commands that use the symbols on those keys, and will want to remap those as well. For example, [`g#`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#g%23) and [`g*`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#gstar):

```
nnoremap g3 g#
nnoremap g8 g*
```

And then you'll start finding [more](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#g%26) and [more](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#g0).

Maybe it's not that bad, but it feels like it's not the best solution for this problem. I think I'd recommend looking into keyboard mappings at the O.S. level, or at least terminal emulator. Some advantages of that would be:

- That would work in any program, not just Vim.
- That would work in Vim regardless of mode and whether the mapped character is part of a multi-character command.
- That would work even for new mappings introduced by plug-ins that include the remapped symbols.
- You could remap the numeric keys on the top row, but leave the keypad untouched so it would still produce numbers (with, or perhaps even without, NumLock.) With the Vim mappings, you're affecting all of them the same, since you can't tell them apart.

So I think there are better solutions to this problem than Vim mappings... But if you go that way, then consider the multi-character mappings as part of what you need to handle.

Comment: I already wrote a new keyboard layout in X and was using it successfully, until I noticed the computer was missing keypresses when switching windows (due to the policy of one layout per individual window). This is why I wanted to shift the numrow just in Vim, and maybe just in specific languages (CSS is better with the normal numrow). I'm still not sure what's better though. I'm already finding new commands that need remapping, as you said.

Comment: Consider a global keyboard layout in X and keep two layouts around with a key combination to switch between them, then you don't have the problem with switching windows (since the layout is global) and you can switch back to numbers on the top row when convenient. (I'm no expert on X, so not 100% sure this is doable, but I'd imagine it would be.)

Comment: Yes, a global layout is actually the default policy. Will give it a try, it does seem like a simpler solution indeed.